# Question about proof of Chebychev's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am completely new to measure theory and probability theory, my question may be silly but I am confused. Let me first state the theorem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, B, P)$ where $\Omega$ is a sample space, $B$ is a Borel set and $P$ is a probability measure. Then for all $\lambda>0$,
$P(|X|>\lambda)\leq\frac{E(|X|)}{\lambda}$.

The proof goes like this:

As $|X|$ is a non-negative random variable, $E(|X|)$ makes sense. Note that

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(|X|) &= \int_{|X|>\lambda}|X|dP + \int_{|X|<\lambda}|X|dP \\
&\geq \int_{|X|>\lambda}|X|dP \\
&\geq \int_{|X|>\lambda}\lambda dP \\
&\geq \lambda P(|X|>\lambda)
\end{aligned}
$$

My questions are:

(1) Why there is a random variable $Y$ in the statement of the theorem?
(2) I know that $E(X)$=$\int_{\Omega}XdP$, But I don't understand how they have written the integral over $|X|>\lambda $ and $|X|<\lambda$; maybe I am missing something here.

What I have understood is that basically $|X|>\lambda$ means $\{\omega\in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega)>\lambda\}$ so with the help of this and $|X|<\lambda$ we are covering all of $\Omega$. I would be thankful if someone answered these two questions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. I don't know why there is a random variable $Y$ in the statement of the theorem; it should not be there at all. Also, if $(\Omega, B, P)$ is your probability space, $B$ should not be a Borel set, but it should be a event space, i.e., $\sigma$-algebra.
2. They can not write the integral like this. You were right about them splitting up the sample space $\Omega$ into two sections, the problem is that they forgot where $|X|=\lambda$. This is not like Riemann integration, where we can forget about "singleton values" (loosely speaking), because here we are talking about values in the *range*, not the domain.

Here is a correct statement of the theorem and modified version of your proof (the inequality of your statement was correct, but I strengthened it):

**Theorem** (Chebychev)**.** If $X$ is a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,B,P)$, then $P(|X|\geq \lambda)\leq\frac{E(|X|)}{\lambda}$.

*Proof.* We have $$ 
\begin{aligned}
E(|X|)&=\int_{|X| \geq \lambda} |X| dP + \int_{|X| < \lambda} |X| dP \\
&\geq \int_{|X| \geq \lambda} |X| dP \\
&\geq  \int_{|X| \geq \lambda} \lambda dP \\
&\geq \lambda P(|X| \geq \lambda),
\end{aligned}$$

so divide through by $\lambda$ to get the result.